# How do you start distributed tensorflow session

Tags: tensorflow

I have been having a hard time starting a distributed tensorflow session. I have been using MPI to start the jobs and have version running that uses mpi to aggregate work, but code is much simpler in pure tensor flow could anyone help me be figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
jobs = ["localhost:222"+str(rank) for i in range(size)] #creates the workers
cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"local": jobs}) 
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="local", task_index=rank) 
with tf.device("/job:local/task:"+str(rank)): #assigns the devices
    #code to make tensors 
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate) 
    optimizer=tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer(optimizer, replicas_to_aggregate=size, # syncs the work
        total_num_replicas=size, 
        replica_id=rank, 
        name="Fact")
    optimizer = optimizer.minimize(cost,global_step=global_step)
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables() 
print "Network initialization done in core", rank 
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(rank == 0), logdir="/tmp/train_logs",init_op=init_op,saver=None,recovery_wait_secs=100,global_step=global_step) 
sess_config = tf.ConfigProto()
with sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(server.target,config=sess_config) as sess: # all replicas frezze here and never start working
    print "Started trainning on process", rank 
        for epoch in range(1):
            _, c,g = sess.run([optimizer, cost,global_step], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y}) #master freezes here as it attempts to aggregate results even if it is the only one working and size is set to 1. The code will not block if optimizer is not SyncReplicas 
sv.stop()# never gets here`
```

Comment: What are you expecting to have happen, and what is actually happening?

Comment: The typical reason for this kind of hang is that the `init_op` - which runs only on the chief (i.e. rank 0 process) - does not initialize *all* of the variables. Can you share the code you use in `#code to make tensors`, as the problem is probably in there.